# C# String Was Not Recognised As Valid DateTime

Tags: c#, csv, datetime

I am trying to parse a CSV file, and am passing in the fields needed.

However no matter what I seem to try, I am being told 'String was not recognised as valid DateTime' for the 'RegistrationDate' field.

I know it is this field because when I set this one as a string, and keep 'DateOfBirth' as DateTime, it runs perfectly fine.

Here are the field types and the code in question.

```
public string CustomerId { get; set; } 
public string Forename { get; set; }
public string Surname { get; set; }
public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
public string VehicleId { get; set; }
public string RegistrationNumber { get; set; }
public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
public string Model { get; set; }
public string EngineSize { get; set; }
public DateTime? RegistrationDate { get; set; }
public string InteriorColour { get; set; }
public string HasHelmet { get; set; }
public string VehicleType { get; set; }
```

and

```
public static IEnumerable<CarData> CsvParser()
    {
        using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(csv_file_path))
        {
            parser.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
            parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = false;

            parser.ReadLine();

            while (!parser.EndOfData)
            {
                string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();

                yield return new CarData()
                {
                    CustomerId = fields[0],
                    Forename = fields[1],
                    Surname = fields[2],
                    DateOfBirth = DateTime.Parse(fields[3]),
                    VehicleId = fields[4],
                    RegistrationNumber = fields[5],
                    Manufacturer = fields[6],
                    Model = fields[7],
                    EngineSize = fields[8],
                    RegistrationDate = DateTime.ParseExact(fields[9], "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                    InteriorColour = fields[10],
                    HasHelmet = fields[11],
                    VehicleType = fields[12]
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

For now I have been trying .ParseExact but it is still throwing the error.. any ideas?

EDIT: Example of the string I am trying to parse is '2007-02-28'

In regards to potential duplicate question, I believe I have already tried that solution in the code above.

Comment: What is the string you are trying to parse? The simple answer is, it is not in a valid date time format, but we can't sure unless you tell us what it is

Comment: @Dave The string is as such "2007-02-28"

Comment: @BethanyJayneEvans post the example in your question, **not in a comment**

Comment: @BethanyJayneEvans use a debugger and put a breakpoint on that line, check if that field (field[9]) actually has the value you're expecting.

Comment: Please read [MCVE] guidance on posting code. The string you've add in comment parses perfectly fine by code shown - please delete or [edit] post with real minimal code (one line) including data necessary to show the problem inline in the question.

Comment: @maccettura the comment OP provided *is not* example of the problem. Just example.

Comment: Keep in mind that even a simple space before or after the date value could break the parse

Comment: Check your input. One of the values may be blank.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Okay, one input value is empty for this particular field. What is the solution for this?

Comment: You are missing a value. Sounds like a `null` to me.

Comment: @JuanR Okay it makes sense now. The CSV file has some null values. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You are parsing null values in your CSV.**

When dealing with CSV files sometimes you may not expect the value to exist.

```
private DateTime ParseDateTimeField(string date)
{
    //If our string is not null
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(date))
        return DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    else
        //Do something like return a specific date or maybe today.
        //return DateTime.Today;
}
```

In your code:

```
 RegistrationDate = ParseDateTimeField(fields[9]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the field for null or empty values before attempting to parse.

Change this line of the constructor:

```
RegistrationDate = DateTime.ParseExact(fields[9], "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
```

To this:

```
RegistrationDate = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fields[9]) ? null : DateTime.ParseExact(fields[9].Trim(), "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
```

Make sure subsequent logic accounts for the `RegistrationDate` field possibly being `null`.

Answer (score 0):

`Sven`'s function can be written to handle any possible incorrect information in the cells that are supposed to hold a valid date/time value:

```
private DateTime? ParseDateTimeField(string date)
{
    DateTime value;
    if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out value))
        return null; 
    return value;
}
```

This should make your code more robust since it will not crash for invalid values that are not just empty cells.